# Reading multiple excel files in R

Tags: r

I have a for loop to read excel files and bind them. I am using below code to execute. But even though the number of rows are constant (B5:C20), I am getting below error

```
> file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx', recursive = TRUE, path = paste0(getwd(),"/Profits"))
> profit <- data.frame()
> for (i in 1:length(file.list)) {
+   profit  <- cbind(profit, read_excel(paste0(getwd(),"/Profits/",file.list[i]),range = "B5:C20",col_names = c("A","B")))
+ }
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 16
```

Not sure what wrong I am doing here. Can anyone help me

Comment: I think the reason for the error is that profit (made by `profit <- data.frame()`) has no rows, where as the second file you are trying to write to it has 16 rows. One solution would be to read all of your .xlsx files into a list and then bind them together: lapply(file.list, function(x) read_excel(paste0(getwd(), '/Profits/',x), range='B5:C20', col_names=c('A', 'B'). You can then recursively bind these together with either a do.call or similar.

Comment: Perfect. I got it. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: I'm guessing you meant to use `rbind` rather than `cbind`.